# which is safe to use a .py file or .ini file to store credentials?

Tags: python-3.x, bots

I have a bot running on twitter that takes posts from Reddit and uploads them on to Twitter. I store all the credentials in a config.py file. That is, I store all the API keys and secret keys in the config.py file and then import the config.py file into the main script.

Is it safe to use config.py file on servers or should I use other types of files like .ini or .yml or .json to access those credentials?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you running inside a docker?

Comment: The file type does not matter. What matters is who has access to the file.

Comment: @Aaron_ab No, I'm not using docker